# Download web page and remove content except for one html table

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep, cut

I am given a large html report from another department quite regularly that requires a fair amount of manual work to edit into a format that is required.

I'd like to work a bit smarter. I can download the page via:

```
wget -qO- <https://the_page.html>
```

However I just want to carve out a table that begins:

```
<!-- START Daily Keystroke
```

It goes on and on for many lines of html and always ends:

```
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Before the next load of data is begun. I need everything in between these patterns in one chunk of text /file.

I played around with sed and awk which I am not really familiar with but it seems without knowing how many lines are going to be in the file each time these tools are not appropriate for this task. It seems something that can work more on specific patterns is appropriate.

That being the case I can install other utilities potentially. If anyone has any experience of something that might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesting `gawk` cutting on first multi-line record. Followed by `sed`, head trimming till `<!-- ...`.

```
gawk 'NR==1{print}' RS="</table>\n</div>\n</div>" input.html |sed '0,/<!-- START Daily Keystroke/d'
```

Or without intermediate file:

```
wget -qO- <https://the_page.html>| \
gawk 'NR==1{print}' RS="</table>\n</div>\n</div>" | \
sed '0,/<!-- START Daily Keystroke/d'
```

This script, tested to work with provided sample text.

#### `gawk` Explanation:

The `gawk` script cuts input text in first occurrence of.

```
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Aligned to the left margin.

##### `NR==1{print}`

Print `gawk` record number 1 only.

The first record is identify by all text (many lines), terminated with matched pattern in `RS` variable.

##### `RS="</table>\n</div>\n</div>"`

A regular expression (`RegExp`) That match the  `gawk` multi-line record separator.

In case you want to include indenting whitespaces in the RegExp. Try:

```
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

`RS="[[:space:]]*</table>[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*</div>[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*</div>"`

#### `sed` Explanation:

Remove all line till first occurrence of RegExp `<!-- START Daily Keystroke`

##### `0,/<!-- START Daily Keystroke/`

`sed` lines range. Starting from line `0`, till first line that match `<!-- START Daily Keystroke/`

##### `d`

Delete/ignore all lines in range.

Comment: Thanks @Dudi I tried this and it produced no output. I tested it by downloading the page to my host with curl and using cat on the file with a pipe into gawk. I actually don't get anything still. Is the double equals operand correct in this instance? If I just use one, I do get output... but it just dumps the whole file. Even with the rest of the commands (with gawk etc). So, I can't get it to work still, unfortunately. cat file.html | gawk 'NR=1{print}' RS="</table>\n</div>\n</div>" | sed '0,/START Daily Keystroke/d'

Comment: Added some explanation to the answer. Probably the data provided in the question to identify `end of interesting section` is not fully accurate.

Answer (score 3):

> I played around with sed and awk

Be warned that these are best suited for working with things which might be described using regular expressions, HTML could not be. HTML parsers are devices which are destined for usage with HTML documents. Generally you should avoid using regular expression for dealing with Chomsky Type-2 contraptions.

> That being the case I can install other utilities potentially. If
> anyone has any experience of something that might work?

I suggest trying [`hxselect`](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/hxselect.html) as it allows easy extraction of element(s) matching CSS selector. It does use stdin so you might pipe output into it, consider following example: I want to download [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) page and extract its' title tag, then I can do:

```
wget -q -O - https://www.example.com | hxselect -i 'title'
```

if you encounter some ill-formed HTML you might use `hxclean` which will try to make it acceptable to hxselect like so

```
wget -q -O - https://www.example.com | hxclean | hxselect -i 'title'
```

If either of above works with your URL then you might start looking for CSS selector which describe only table you want to extract. See [CSS selectors reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for available features. I am unable to craft selector without seeing whole source of page.